# Loop through array in joining tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

am trying to join tables, i have 3 models

```
class ClassAdviser < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :feeds
  has_many :students
end

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hod
  belongs_to :class_adviser
  belongs_to :student
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :class_adviser
  has_many :feeds
end
```

How do iterate through the array and get all rows in the joined table,i want to display the details of each student individually.Below is what i tried but i get only details of feeds.

```
@get_stds = current_class_adviser.students
@get_stds.each do |d|
@students << d.id
end
@students = @students.flatten

for number in @students
  @feeds = Feed.joins(:student).where ("student_id = '#{number}'")
end
```

Comment: This looks like a class [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why don't you tell us what you're actually trying to do? If, for example, you're trying to get all the `feeds` for all the `students` of the `current_class_adviser`, then you're going about this entirely in the wrong way.

Comment: Thats exactly what am trying to do, i actually do have the feeds from the students, i just need a way to output identity of each student alongside their feed.

Comment: That's not at all what your question ask, tho. BTW, hopefully you're getting the feeds by doing `Feed.where(student: current_class_adviser.students)` because that's the way to do it, not with mapping or looping or arrays or whatnot.

Comment: I have the feeds already, i just need to make the class adviser aware of each students feed, i.e display student info along with the feed, i have to join the feeds and students tables first,and loop through the array to display a student's info alongside his / her feed.

Comment: Presumably in a view, yes? I think it would be helpful if you show the view where you're trying to display the feed along with the student info since, if I understand it, that's what your question is really about. And, perhaps, the relevant code from the controller, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1) I think it is weird that a feed belongs_to a class_advisor.  I would change that to be a class_advisor has_many feeds through students.

2) You should be able to just do
`@students = @students.flatten
@feeds = @students.map(&:feeds)`

Comment: Thanks bro,but it didn't work, i get an error that says "undefined method `feeds' for 3:Fixnum" @ruby_newbie

Comment: Your first point is a great one! Your second point is off. It should be: `Feed.where(student: current_class_adviser.students)`.

Answer (score 0):

To display each student detail along with their respective feed,here is what i did

Controller

```
 @std_feeds = Feed.where(student: current_class_adviser.students)
```

View

```
<tbody>
    <% @std_feeds.each do |feed| %>                                         
        <tr class="table-row">
         <td class="table-img">
            <p><%=feed.student.first_name%> <%= feed.student.last_name%></p>
             <div><%= feed.created_at.strftime('%d %b %Y')%></div>
          </td>
         <td class="table-text" rowspan="1">
        <%= feed.subject %>
      <p class='message'><%= feed.message %></p>
     </td>                         
     <td class="march">
      <h6>DELETE</h6> 
     </td>
     </tr>
   <%end%> 
   </tbody>
```

This @std_feeds contains both the student details and feed details,all thanks to Rails Association.